# Why are these two probability statements different (leading to two different formulas and probabilities)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'd like to know why this

> Given that a randomly selected spring is defective find the probability that it was
>   produced by machine C.

is different to this

> Find the probability that a randomly selected spring is defective and is produced by machine C.

It would seem that the first sounds like it's asking for the second; I'm unsure about the differences, and why they are different.

---

I know the first is asking for: $$Pr\left( \mbox{C}|D \right)=\frac{Pr\left( \mbox{C}\cap D \right)}{Pr\left( D \right)}$$

and the second is asking for: $$Pr\left( \mbox{C}\cap D \right)$$

---

The above questions are based on this information:

> In a factory machines A, B, and C are all producing springs of the same length. Of the total production of springs in the factory, machine A produces 35% and machines B and C produce 25% and 40% respectively. Of their production machines A, B and C produce 3%, 6% and 5% defective springs respectively.

Comment: Well, the second question is phrased ambiguously but the way I read it:  The first question is comparing different machines, the second just looks at one machine.  Imagine that you had three machines, A,B,C each of which produces defective springs 1% of the time.  Then the answer to question #1 is $\frac 13$ while the answer to question #2 is $\frac 1{100}$

Comment: I'll put more info in the question

Comment: In light of all the new information:  have you been able to answer either question?

Comment: Yes but im asking about the theory, why we use those two different formulas; why the two questions are different when they sound like they're asking for the same thing

Comment: For the reason I gave (and you gave as well, in the edited version).  The first is comparing different machines.  The second only asks about C.  What are your answers?

Comment: As an example:  if someone came in and perfected all the machines, but left C alone, then the answer to the first question would surely change (it would now be $1$), while the answer to the second question would be unchanged.

Comment: $Pr\left( \mbox{C}\cap D \right)=0.4\cdot 0.05=0.02$ and $Pr\left( \mbox{C}|D \right)=\frac{0.02}{0.0455}≈0.4396$

Comment: Agreed!  But you can see from what you calculated that, in answering the first question you used information about all three machines.  In answering the second question you ignored A,B and only looked at C.

Comment: If you want a different way of looking at it: the first question looks just at the collection of defective springs, and the role C plays there.  The second question question looks at the entire collection of springs and the role C plays in that.

Comment: I get it, because we know that the spring is defective, we are just looking at how the machines are; how they resulted in the defectiveness and the probability. The second question asks how C itself would result in defectiveness, right ?

Comment: Yes.  To be clear:  whenever I encounter a probability or statistics question in an applied setting, I go over it very carefully with whoever is asking it.  Small differences in wording change the meaning of the question a lot and I've seen a lot of confusion arising from that.

Comment: Yeh thanks for that, you answered my question clearly